# Exchangelib: Can't connect to server

Tags: python, ssl, exchangelib

so recently I tried myself with Exchangelib, but I currently can't solve the issue. Heres my code:

```
    from exchangelib import DELEGATE, Account, Credentials, IMPERSONATION
    from exchangelib.configuration import Configuration

    config = Configuration(
        server='https://XXX',
        credentials=Credentials(username='XXX\\XXX', password='XXX')
    )
    account = Account(
        primary_smtp_address='mail@mail.com',
        config=config,
        autodiscover=False,
        access_type=DELEGATE,
    )

    for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:20]:
        print(item.subject, item.sender, item.datetime_received)
```

Currently I receive the following error:

```
    File "Project/Exchange/standardoutlook2.py", line 23, in <module>
        config = Configuration(server='https://XXX', credentials=credentials)
    File "Projectvenv36\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\configuration.py", line 46, in __init__
        version=version
    File "Projectvenv36\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\protocol.py", line 176, in __call__
        protocol = super(CachingProtocol, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "Projectvenv36\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\protocol.py", line 209, in __init__
        name=self.credentials.username)
    File "Projectvenv36\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\transport.py", line 149, in get_service_authtype
        timeout=BaseProtocol.TIMEOUT)
    File "Projectvenv36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 559, in post
        return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
    File "Projectvenv36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 512, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    File "Projectvenv36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 622, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    File "Projectvenv36\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 412, in send
        self.cert_verify(conn, request.url, verify, cert)
    File "Project/Exchange/standardoutlook2.py", line 13, in cert_verify
        }[urlparse(url).hostname]
    KeyError: 'https'
```

I've added the certificate to the certificate of certifi, so when I start any request to the server outside of the code above it works well.

Comment: Your stack trace doesn't match the code you posted. It reports failing in method `cert_verify` at line 13 in `standardoutlook2.py` but you don't have a `cert_verify` method in the posted code.

Comment: I fixed it by myself. It wasn't a certification error. I tried to contacted the server but should have gone instead for the service_endpoint. Fixed it and everything working.
Additionally I've tested it concerning certifi certificates: Exchangelib uses the standard certifi certificate store. I've added my certificate to the store and everything works like a charm.

Comment: Can you please share the required correction? Thanks.